# Unity3D Object is null after initialization in Start()

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am trying to make a few objects and classes interact.
I have two classes. Code is similar. But in `class Building_main` after object is initialized in Start() I can reuse it in functions and in `class House_main` I can not (object is null).`class Building_main` is a child of `class House_main`.

What am I doing wrong?

First class :

```
    public class Building_main : MonoBehaviour {

        public string owner;
        public string producedGoodName;

        private Building_goods goods;
        private House_main house;

        void Start () {
            goods = this.transform.Find("Building_goods").GetComponent<Building_goods>();
            house = this.transform.parent.gameObject.GetComponent<House_main> ();
            UpdateHouseInfo ();
        }

        void UpdateHouseInfo () {
            // reusing objs (house, goods) no error
            house.UpdateGoodInfo (goods.GetGoodByName("sword"), "sword");
        }
```

Second class :

```
public class House_main : MonoBehaviour {

    public string owner;

    private House_goods goods;

    void Start () {
        // obj (goods) is not null
        goods = this.transform.Find("House_goods").GetComponent<House_goods>();
       // i can use
       // goods.AddAmountToGoodByName (value, name);
    }

    public void UpdateGoodInfo (int value, string name) {
        // obj (goods) is null
        goods.AddAmountToGoodByName (value, name);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like my child class ( `class Building_main` ) Start() function is executing before parent class ( `class House_main` ) Start() function.

So in `class House_main` object `goods` is not yet assigned when I am calling `function UpdateGoodInfo`, because I am calling it using `class Building_main` Start()

```
`class Building_main {
        Start() {
          UpdateHouseInfo ();
        }
}`
```

Didn't know this.

Comment: You can also use Awake method in your parent class